# Creating lib of mongoose models not working on import

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I've been trying to create a library of mongo models and helper class that is then shared as an npm module we the rest of my team. The problem I having is the main code I import from lib MongoConnector which process config information and connects to mongo, I also import Model1 and do a find all that call works. But when I import Poller from the same lib and pass it Model1, when it does the find the promise never returns.

Library has 4 files

Model1.ts:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export interface IModel1 {
    draftId: string;
    [k:string]: any;
}

export interface IModel1DocumnetAttrs {
    draftId: string;
    data: string;
    createdBy?: String;
}

export interface IModel1Document extends mongoose.Document {
    draftId: String;
    createdBy: String;
    data: string;
}

export type IModel1Model = mongoose.Model<IModel1Document>;

const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        draftId: {type: String, index: {unique: true }},
        createdBy: String,
        data: String,
    },
    { versionKey: false, strict: false, timestamps: true, },
);

export const Model1: IModel1Model = mongoose.model<IModel1Document, IModel1Model>('Model1', schema);
```

MongoPoller.ts:

```js
import * as Logger from 'bunyan';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export type IMongoPollerCallback<T extends mongoose.Document> = (error: Error | undefined, docs?: T[]) => void;

export class MongoPoller<T extends mongoose.Document> {
    private query: any;
    private callback: IMongoPollerCallback<T>;
    private intervalId: any;
    private readonly log: Logger;
    constructor(private readonly pollingTime: number, private readonly model: typeof mongoose.Model, baseLogger: Logger) {
        this.callback = _.noop;
        this.log = baseLogger.child({ component: 'MongoPoller' });
    }

    public start(query: any, callback: IMongoPollerCallback<T>) {
        this.query = query;
        this.callback = callback;

        this.intervalId = setInterval(() => this.workFunction(), this.pollingTime);
    }

    public stop() {
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }

    public async initial(query: any, callback: IMongoPollerCallback<T>) {
        this.query = query;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.log.info(`Mongo Poller started with initial, ${JSON.stringify(query)}`);

        return this.workFunction();
    }

    public continue() {
        this.log.info(`Mongo Poller told to continue, ${JSON.stringify(this.query)}`);
        this.intervalId = setTimeout(() => this.workFunction(), this.pollingTime);
    }

    private async workFunction() {
        try{
            this.log.info(`Mongo Poller executing workFunction, ${JSON.stringify(this.query)}`);
            const docsp =  this.model.find(this.query).exec();
            const docs = await docsp;
            this.log.info(`Mongo Poller executing workFunction callback with ${docs.length} docs, ${JSON.stringify(this.query)}`);

            this.callback(undefined, docs)

        }
        catch (e){
            this.log.info(`Mongo Poller executing workFunction callback with ERROR ${e.message}, ${JSON.stringify(this.query)}`);
            this.callback(undefined)
        }

    }
}
```

MongoDBConnector.ts:

```js
import Promise = require('bluebird');
import * as Logger from 'bunyan';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { decrypt, IKeyData } from './cryptoUtils';

interface IMongoDatabaseConfig {
    uri?: string;
    fullUri?: string;
    options?: object;
    username?: string;
    password?: string;
    initialDelayMSec?: number;
    finalDelayMSec?: number;
    triesBeforeFinalDelay?: number;
    autoIndex?: boolean;
    debug?:boolean
}

export class MongoDBConnector {
    private readonly mongoConfig: IMongoDatabaseConfig = {};
    private connectionPromise: Promise<any> | undefined;
    private readonly log: Logger;
    constructor(config: IMongoDatabaseConfig, baseLogger: Logger, keyData: IKeyData) {
        this.mongoConfig = config;
        mongoose.set('debug', this.mongoConfig.debug);
        mongoose.set('autoCreate', true);
        this.log = baseLogger.child({ component: 'MongoDBConnector' });
        Object.assign(this.mongoConfig, config);
        if (
            !this.mongoConfig.username ||
            this.mongoConfig.username.trim() === '' ||
            !this.mongoConfig.password ||
            this.mongoConfig.password.trim() === ''
        ) {
            this.mongoConfig.fullUri = `mongodb://${this.mongoConfig.uri}`;
        } else {
            this.mongoConfig.fullUri = `mongodb://${this.mongoConfig.username}:${decrypt(
                this.mongoConfig.password,keyData
            )}@${this.mongoConfig.uri}`;
        }
        this.mongoConfig.autoIndex = true;

        mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    }

    private connectToMongo(numTries: number = 1): any {
        return mongoose
            .connect(<string>this.mongoConfig.fullUri, this.mongoConfig.options)
            .then(() => {
                this.log.info('MongoDB Connected!');

                return mongoose.connection;
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                const timeoutDelayMSec =
                    numTries < <number>this.mongoConfig.triesBeforeFinalDelay
                        ? this.mongoConfig.initialDelayMSec
                        : this.mongoConfig.finalDelayMSec;
                this.log.error(`Issue connecting to MongoDB: ${error.message}`);
                this.log.info(
                    `Retrying connection to MongoDB (attempt #${numTries}). Reconnecting in ${timeoutDelayMSec} ms...`,
                );

                return Promise.delay(<number>timeoutDelayMSec).then(() => {
                    return this.connectToMongo(numTries + 1);
                });
            });
    }

    public connect() {
        if (!this.connectionPromise) {
            this.log.info(`Attempting to connect to MongoDB on ${this.mongoConfig.fullUri}`);
            this.connectionPromise = this.connectToMongo().catch((error: any) => {
                this.connectionPromise = undefined;
                throw error;
            });
        }

        return this.connectionPromise;
    }
}
```

index.ts:

```js
export { Model1 } from './Model1';
export { MongoDBConnector} from './MongoDBConnector';
export {IMongoPollerCallback, MongoPoller}  from './MongoPoller';
```

The Main App :

index.ts:

```js
import * as config from './config/config.json';
import * as keyEventLogger from './logging/keyEventLogger';
import { loggerFactory } from './logging/loggerFactory';


import {
    DraftJudgment,
    IDraftDocument,
    IMongoPollerCallback,
    MongoDBConnector,
    MongoPoller
} from 'exploitmongomodels';

import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import { Promise as bluebird } from 'bluebird';
import * as keyData from './key.json';

global.Promise = bluebird;

const log = loggerFactory('main');

async function main() {
    // adding better logging for uncaught rejected promises
    process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
        log.fatal({ err }, 'uncaught rejection');
    });

    process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
        log.fatal({ err }, 'uncaught exception');
    });

    const mongo = new MongoDBConnector(config.database.mongo, log, keyData);

    await mongo.connect();

    keyEventLogger.logKeyEvent(keyEventLogger.keyEvents.heartBeat, '');

    const d = await DraftJudgment.find({}).exec();
    console.log(d.length); //<- this prints 3
    //const j2 = mongoose.model('DraftJudgment');  <-- this throws an error

    //Set up heart beat for log files
    setInterval(
        () => keyEventLogger.logKeyEvent(keyEventLogger.keyEvents.heartBeat, ''),
        config.logger.heartbeatInterval,
    );

    const judgmentSubmitPoller = new MongoPoller<IDraftDocument>(config.pollingDurationInSec, DraftJudgment, log);

    const judgmentSubmitPollingCB: IMongoPollerCallback<IDraftDocument> = (
        error: Error | undefined,
        docs?: IDraftDocument[],
    ) => {
        if (error) {
            log.error(error, 'Error during judgment mongo polling');
            judgmentSubmitPoller.continue();

            return;
        }
        log.info(`Submit poller triggered submitted judgments`);
        if (!docs) {
            return;
        }
        //do something with the docs object

        log.info(`Submit poller triggered with ${docs.length} submitted judgments`);

        judgmentSubmitPoller.continue();
    };
    judgmentSubmitPoller.initial({ status: 'submitted' }, judgmentSubmitPollingCB);

    const judgmentPendingPoller = new MongoPoller<IDraftDocument>(config.pollingDurationInSec, DraftJudgment, log);

    const judgmentPendingPollingCB: IMongoPollerCallback<IDraftDocument> = (
        error: Error | undefined,
        docs?: IDraftDocument[],
    ) => {
        if (error) {
            log.error(error, 'Error during judgment mongo polling');
            judgmentSubmitPoller.continue();

            return;
        }
        if (!docs) {
            return;
        }

        //do something with the docs object

        log.info(`Pending poller triggered with ${docs.length} submitted judgments`);

        judgmentPendingPoller.continue();
    };
    //judgmentPendingPoller.initial({ $query: { status: 'pending' } }, judgmentPendingPollingCB);

    //tslint:disable-next-line
    while (true) {}
}

main();
```

In MongoPoller#workFunction , docsp promise never resolves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was a bit embarrassing, the problem was the while loop at the bottom of main. Added by another dev; we both assumed it was needed to prevent node from exiting. Well it is not, and because the loop was so tight it never allowed time for the promise to resolve.

Live and learn.